# Getting started with data visualization. What is a good 'hello world' type of project?

Tags: data-visualization, data-science

I have been gaining interest in data visualization lately. I especially enjoy articles with narrative driven data-viz like the ones in http://polygraph.cool/ for example.

What would be a great 'hello world' project to learn about conveying information effective through data viz? I'm not sure where to start.

Thanks!

Comment: Just start, it almost doesn't matter where. That is the point of a "hello world" project. Find an example that you like and shamelessly reproduce it. There is nothing original in printing "hello world". Figure out *how* they did what they did.

Comment: @JohnColeman thx John! I thinks these are words I needed to hear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two subreddits come to mind. [Here](https://www.reddit.com/r/dataisbeautiful/) you can find some nice applications of data visualizations, and [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/datasets/) you can keep up to date datasets that get published. Put those two together and you can come up with some novel ideas. Looking forward to seeing your stuff in /r/dataisbeautiful!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I forgot about reddit, but from now on I'll def start from there. :)

Answer (score 0):

How about starting with a data density app?

If you search on my name and "data density" you'll find some routines on the web, but that would be cheating. The way the system works is to take reciprocal of squared distance plus a fudge factor to prevent 1/d when the sample pixel point is very close to a data point. So you get the density of a 2D scatterplot.

You then need a nice visual representation of a linear scale, using colours to represent value changes. I'll give you those, I have several colour palettes at

http://www.malcolmmclean.site11.com/www/datadensity/colourschemes.c
http://www.malcolmmclean.site11.com/www/datadensity/colourschemes.h